# Invoke a Perl script from Powershell and stores the script output in a variable

Tags: powershell, perl

Could someone try to help me out to run a Perl program from a PowerShell script? I'm trying to save the script results into a PowerShell variable.

So far, I have tried the below from the Powershell ISE. But it does not seem to be working.

```
perl 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ABC\ABC Software\bin\testcheck.pl -print verbose'
```

Powershell Script Path: `C:\MyScripts`
Perl Program Dir: `C:\Program Files (x86)\ABC\ABC Software\perl\bin\perl.exe`

Comment: `perl 'C:\Pr...in\testcheck.pl -print verbose'` -> `perl 'C:\Pr...in\testcheck.pl' -print verbose`. If that doesn't help you need to provide more information. Did you add the path to the Perl executable in your PATH envirenment variable. Also, how *exactly* is it "not working"?

Comment: Can I explicitly mention the Perl executable path in the script itself?

Comment: I'm getting the following message                  perl : The term 'perl' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.

Comment: Re "*I'm getting the following message perl : The term 'perl' is not recognized as*", That means that `perl.exe` isn't in your path. You'll need to provide the full path to `perl.exe` (`& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ABC\ABC Software\perl\bin\perl.exe' 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ABC\ABC Software\bin\testcheck.pl' -print verbose`)

Comment: Re "*Can I explicitly mention the Perl executable path in the script itself?*", You could create a file association. Then, you'd simply treat the script as the program to run ( (`& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ABC\ABC Software\bin\testcheck.pl' -print verbose`)